# Использование string в функциях scanf и printf

Tags: c++

Могут ли функции `scanf` и `printf` работать с переменными типа `string`? Если да, то как это сделать, например, в данном коде?

```
scanf_s("%s", &TempFirstName);
pSMass[i].FirstName = TempFirstName;
printf_s("%s", pSMass[i].FirstName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это, конечно, бред - использовать функции C с классами C++, но в принципе можно, хотя и не так, как указали вы.

`printf` - очень просто, передавать надо результат вызова `c_str()`:

```
string s;
...
printf("%s",s.c_str());
```

Со `scanf` все гораздо хуже! Непосредственно со `scanf` не поработаешь, нужно сначала выделить в строке место, а потом передать указатель, но так как до C++17 `.data()` возвращает `const char*`, то формально следует использовать `&s[0]`. Но все знакомые мне компиляторы кушают и `.data()` - см., например, http://ideone.com/nzJE2S. VC++ тоже съедает - с предупреждением.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s;
    s.reserve(100);
    scanf("%s",s.data());
    printf("You wrote: %s, %d chars\n",s.c_str(),s.length());
}
```

Но! Беда в том, что `string` при этом **не знает**, что в нем находится какая-то строка, и если вы запросите длину строки - она будет нулевой. Это просто использован буфер. Поэтому здесь в принципе никто ничего гарантировать не может. Тот же VC++ ухитряется верно обновить длину с помощью `s = s.data()`, но GCC, например, при этом строку просто обнуляет. Указать корректный способ обойти это затруднение я не могу.

Но, по большому счету, это правильно, потому что даже такое изменение строки - не через ее интерфейс, а через указатель на внутренний буфер - уже нарушает принцип инкапсуляции.

Так что `scanf`'уйте в массив `char`, а им инициализируйте `string` - это корректно и надежно. Хотя и просто смешно при наличии соответствующий возможностей C++ для считывания строк...

Comment: Да, так и сделал, сначала прочитал в символьный массив, затем инициализировал им строковое поле.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм считывания:

```
string s;//создание
reserve(100);//выделение памяти, scanf не выделяет память, так что может уйти за границы
scanf("%s",s.begin());//считывание. Обратите внимание, что .c_str и .data нельзя использовать из-за того, что они создают копию строки, а исходная не меняется
s=s.c_str();//нормализация, для понимания надо понять, что результат scanf - массив со строкой и \0 в конце. Сдесь это приводится к норм виду
```

алгоритм вывода:

```
printf("%s",s.begin());//тут всё просто
```

и это работает